# Adding imageView on ViewGroup with setOnTouchListener

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

**EDIT: This question was solved!**

i'm facing with a, hopefully, simple problem. What i need it's to show/add image on onTouch position when the user click on the Image/Area.
  This is the layout:

```
activity_test_diff.xml

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".TestDiff"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_rectangle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_test_diff1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/click_check_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/check_green_48dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/click_check_ko"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@drawable/close_red_48dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_test_diff2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The parent group of the Relative Layout it's a LinearLayout, but i don't care if someone touch outside of RelativeLayout. This is the code to handle the touch:

```
TestDiff.java

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_diff);

    RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);

    relative.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = ev.getAction();

    final int evX = (int) ev.getX();
    final int evY = (int) ev.getY();

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            int x = (int) ev.getX();
            int y = (int) ev.getY();
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            lp.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
            iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
            iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.check_green_48dp));
            ((ViewGroup) v).addView(iv);

            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // On the UP, we do the click action.
            // The hidden image (img_rectangle) has three different hotspots on it.
            // The colors are red, blue, and yellow.
            // Use img_rectangle to determine which region the user
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

And this is the coming error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(android.view.View$OnTouchListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
```

Mean someone can figure out what's happening!
  Thanks

Comment: RelativeLayout `layout_relative`is not in the hierarchy. If this is your activity make sure `layout_relative` is present within the layout `activity_test_diff`.

Comment: edited the question, it's just my mistake, type error on posting

Comment: Well this is not what I asked for. There is no way for me to tell weather the layout you've posted is infact `activity_test_diff` or some other layout, 1. because you've not posted name on top, 2. You say RelativeLayout is a child of LinearLayout but I don't see any LinearLayout wrapping around `layout_relative`. Please refer to [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Abbas, question updated!

Comment: @justo Does the problem persist with *this* code?

Comment: @rushi yep, and i can't see what i'm doing wrong

Comment: can you comment out irrelevant code (all `<ImageViews>` and code in `onTouch`) and see if it still exists (*it should*). This way you will have [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hmm... seems like you are doing everything correctly. Make sure your layout file is inside a folder named `layout` and not any variation e.g. `layout-large`, `layout-sw600` etc.

Comment: @rushi i've teste without all the unnecessary code, but the problem persist. If you want i can grab the code from the question.

Comment: @Abbas i've 2 layout, one for the standard display like smartphone and one for the large display like tablet. How this can generate the problem "null object reference"?

Comment: @Abbas , you was right! I'm doing all correctly except testing on the corresponding device :'( . Basically i'm working on a smartphone layout and testing on physical tablet device. So, i'm an idiot!

Comment: @justo glad it worked out. :-)

Answer (score 0):

on the xml layout you have :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
```

in the java code you have

`RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_relative)`;

you reversed relative & layout words